# How to INSERT dynamic info in MySQL table using Node/Express JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, stored-procedures

I am working on a react app with a Node/Express JS back end.
I am trying to insert a value, based on the input of the user, into MySQL database. Here is my Node post request:

```
// To create a new user account
app.post('/createUser', function(req, res) {
    console.log('in createUser');
    const {firstName, lastName, username, passcode, email} = req.query;
    const CreateUser = `CALL CreateUser('${firstName}', '${lastName}', 
        '${username}', '${passcode}', '${email}')`;
    mysqlConnection.query(CreateUser, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            res.status(500)
            res.send("Could not create user account.")
        } else {
            console.log('create user cart');
            console.log(`${req.query.username}`);
            const CreateUserCart = `CALL CreateUserCart('${req.query.username}')`;
            mysqlConnection.query(CreateUserCart, (error1, result1) => {
                if(error1) {
                    res.status(500)
                    res.send("Could not create user account.")
                } else {
                    res.status(201)
                    res.send("Account successfully created!")
                }
            })  
        }
    })
});
```

The first stored procedure, CreateUser, is working fine. What I want to do is take the value in req.query of username and pass it to the stored procedure called CreateUserCart. Here is that stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`lsharon`@`%` PROCEDURE `CreateUserCart`(IN
username VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO SHOPPING_CART(CustomerID) 
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE Username = username;  
END
```

My desire is to insert the CustomerID that belongs to the user I just created into the shopping cart table. However, currently it is inserting every CustomerID into that table, even if it already exists there. I only want to insert the ID for the single user who just created an account.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Comment: **WARNING**: Always use [placeholder values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values) to maintain separation between query and data. Using template strings creates [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You'll also want to get out of the habit of using template strings with one thing in them. In general terms `\`${x}\`` should be `x`.

Comment: The next question I have is why all the stored procedures? These queries are more easily defined and, importantly, altered in the application code. Stored procedures require rolling out schema changes any time you change anything, and this can make testing two versions in parallel impossible.

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like names and email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users. Using `45` as a length is downright bizarre and will be confusing to users.

Comment: I am working on a final project for my college database class, and one requirement is to use stored procedures when interacting with the database. Where you saying I should change `${req.query.username}` to `${username}`?

Comment: If you're interpolating one thing in a template string you're really not using a template. I'm saying instead of `f(\`${x}\`)` instead do `f(x)`. It's way less clutter and means the same thing. Templates are only useful when you're interpolating more than one thing, or are adding things on, like `\`${x}?\``.

Comment: That is a good point about the VARCHAR(255) and I will definitely change that. However, I originally had it as VARCHAR(255) and had the same issue.

Comment: The `VARCHAR(255)` thing is to prevent unexpected truncation errors that can be super frustrating. It doesn't fix any bugs per-se, but prevents confusion in the future.

Comment: Normally I'd approach this by using [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/) which makes running queries a lot more pleasant since it supports promises and `await`. You should be able to fix this code if you can identify the errors you're experiencing. Don't just dump out a 500 status, write something to your log with the details contained in `err`. You need that information to get to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query in your sp says

```
    WHERE Username = username;
```

Your column names are case insensitive. So `Username = username` matches every row in your `CUSTOMER`. It's a version of `WHERE 1 = 1` -- always true.

Try changing the name of your parameter, something like this:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateUserCart` (IN newUsername VARCHAR(45) )
  BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO SHOPPING_CART(CustomerID) 
     SELECT CustomerID 
      FROM CUSTOMER 
  WHERE Username = newUsername;  
END
```

MySQL stored programs are tons of fun to troubleshoot, eh?  Lots of people avoid them for that reason.  On the other hand, many large enterprises use lots of stored programs to interact with their data. But those enterprises usually pay the rather large licensing fees for Oracle or SQL Server. Those databases have better stored programming languages and tools. So, if you work at one of those places, you'll appreciate having a little bit of exposure to stored programs.

**Pro tip** there's a much more robust way to handle this workflow. Get your first stored procedure to end with something like

```
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() CustomerID;
```

This will make the procedure return a resultset, which you can handle just as if it were a SELECT query. [LAST_INSERT_ID() gets the autoincrement value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) from the most recent INSERT.

Then read that customer id from your resultset, and pass it as a parameter to `CreateUserCart` rather than the customer's name.